# Developing with Unreal Engine 4 and Android Studio simultaneously

Tags: android, android-studio, unreal-engine4

I utilize Android Studio with several different customizations to develop cross-platform apps (Android NDK, experimental Gradle and CrystaX NDK for C++ development), and I am interested in coding my first game with the Unreal Engine for Android.

I am curious if anyone else is doing both customized Android Studio development alongside Unreal+Android development, and **how they are doing so**, as I do not want to disrupt my current Android development environment.

It's Paragraph 1 from [Unreal's Android Quick Start Guide](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Platforms/Android/GettingStarted/) that concerns me, which seems to assume I don't want to continue using my current Android Studio setup:

`If you have other versions of the Android SDK installed (or, older versions of CodeWorks for Android), we recommend that you uninstall them and install CodeWorks for Android, using the CodeWorks for Android installer that's being distributed with UE4.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have both installed and can confirm what JonS states. I know the Unreal documentation says to remove the Android SDK before installing Codeworks for Android, but install paths are different from one another.

I haven't encountered any issues here.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you keep UE4 development in Visual Studio, I don't see any problems?